# How to rotate multi-tile structure on grid?

Tags: unity, 2d, mathematics, matrix, grid

I need to be able to place structures in my game that **span multiple tiles and can also be rotated**.
My idea on how to solve this would be to use 2D arrays that hold data about the structure.

EXAMPLE: (simplified)

Crafting table layout: `XOX`

`X` - data
`O` - data, but also used as a pivot point

If we were to rotate it clockwise, it'd look like this:

```
X
O
X
```

My problem lies in that these positions have to be real-world coordinates, so here's the above example again but in a way that makes sense for my actual grid in-game. (replacing the X and O with coords):

```
(0,1)(1,1)(2,1)
```

And now, rotated clockwise (around the pivot point, which is `(1,1)`):

```
(1,2)
(1,1)
(1,0)
```

Another example purely for more information, but more complex (2x3 array):

Complex workstation (**(6,4) IS THE PIVOT!**):

```
(5,5)(6,5)(7,5)
(5,4)(6,4)(7,4)
```

Rotate it counterclockwise and we should get this:

```
(5,5)(6,5)
(5,4)(6,4)
(5,3)(6,3)
```

I have tried and succeeded in doing it only on a conceptual level with the "X" and "O"s, but I don't know how to implement actual coordinates.

I've never dealt with rotation matrices before so any advice, suggestion or solution on how to implement this is appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a conventional application of a rotation matrix. How have you tried computing these rotated coordinates so far, and where have you run into trouble you need help solving?

Comment: I have tried and succeeded in doing it only on a conceptual level with the "X" and "O"s, but I don't know how to implement actual coordinates. This might be obvious to someone who's dealt with matrices before, but I haven't, and I don't even know how to begin solving this problem. Any help, advice, or solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rotate a 2D point \$\vec p\$ around a center coordinate \$\vec c\$ by treating it as though it had a third dimension with a value of one, and multiplying it by a special matrix:

$$\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix}p_x^\prime\\p_y^\prime \end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix}a & -b & c_x -ac_x +bc_y\\b & a & c_y - bc_x - ac_y\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}p_x\\p_y\\1\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}ap_x - bp_y +c_x -ac_x -bc_y\\bp_x + ap_y + c_y - bc_x - ac_y\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$

where \$a = \cos \theta\$ and \$b = \sin \theta\$ given your counter-clockwise rotation angle \$\theta\$. In your case, for 90-degree rotations, these will only ever be -1, 0, or 1.

$$\begin{align}
0­°&: \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}
& 90­°&: \begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 & c_x + c_y\\1 & 0 & c_y - c_x\end{bmatrix}\\
180­°&: \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 & 2c_x\\0 & -1 & 2c_y\end{bmatrix}\quad
&270­°&: \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & c_x - c_y\\-1 & 0 & c_y + c_x\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$

You can verify that multiplying any of these matrices by \$\vec c = \begin{bmatrix}c_x\\c_y\\1\end{bmatrix}\$ just yields \$\begin{bmatrix}c_x\\c_y\end{bmatrix}\$ again, so the center point stays fixed for all of these transformations.

Comment: Nevermind. I just tried it again and got it (for a single number...). The real challenge now will be coding everything from scratch and making it work to achieve such a simple thing. Either way, thank you!